# MapBox Android: use padding in the correct way

Tags: android, coordinates, mapbox, bounds, mapbox-android

I am trying to virtually reduce the bounds of MapBox visibleArea for getting a region smaller than the real one. The reason is that I am going to send the coordinates to a service that will return back a list of points and I want to be sure that these points are all visible in map. So I would like to use the padding to virtually reduce the bounds that I am going to send.

Until now I have tried many ways, for example `mapbox.setPadding()` that is deprecated and `CameraUpdateFactory.paddingTo()` but no method seems to work correctly and I do not understand which is the correct approach. The problem is that I am not able to find any guide/tutorial/example that shows up how to correctly use padding and the official documentation on the usage of padding is IMHO quite poor.

**Does anyone found or know something useful on this topic?**

At the moment I am using the most recent mapbox stable version (9.6.1).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/restrict-map-panning and https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/fit-camera-in-bounding-box/ might be helpful.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/restrict-map-panning seems closest to what you're trying to achieve, correct?

Comment: No, my question is related to the correct usage of padding

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the only way I got the padding to work (as you described) was to upgrade to mapbox 10 .

in 9.2 it used to work in a strange way (it was pushing rather than reducing)
but at 9.6 it stopped working completely .